# ImportError when using Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, import

When I add the following line to Google's helloworld example:

```
  from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
```

I get the following error:

```
  <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named reportlab.pdfgen
```

I can get at the reportlab.pdfgen library from the python console.  Why can't I get at it from google's dev_appserver?

Answer (score 3):

Copying the module locally worked.

From

```
Python\Lib\site-packages\reportlab
```

to

```
helloworld\reportlab
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the google app engine does not include all the standard python modules.  I know that anything that works with sockes is disabled, such as urllib.urlopen().