# Import error when trying to access sdk datastore admin

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm getting a "ImportError: No module named simplejson" when trying to access datastore admin on the development server.

After the first time I got this error I installed the simplejson package from slackbuilds (i'm on Slackware). It seems to be working normally, I could import the simplejson module with no errors on the python console.

But the import error persists when I try to access datastore admin, even after installing the module. Restarting the development server didn't do anything.

What could be wrong?

Edit: here's the stacktrace:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 3245, in _HandleRequest
>       self._Dispatch(dispatcher, self.rfile, outfile, env_dict)   File
>   "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 3186, in _Dispatch
>       base_env_dict=env_dict)   File "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 531, in Dispatch
>       base_env_dict=base_env_dict)   File
>   "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 2410, in Dispatch
>       self._module_dict)   File "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 2320, in ExecuteCGI
>       reset_modules = exec_script(handler_path, cgi_path,
>   hook)   File
>   "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 2216, in ExecuteOrImportScript
>       exec module_code in script_module.**dict**   File
>   "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/datastore_admin/main.py",
>   line 30, in 
>       from google.appengine.ext.datastore_admin
>   import copy_handler   File
>   "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 1295, in Decorate
>       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)   File
>   "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 1945, in load_module
>       return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule,
>   fullname, search_path)   File
>   "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 1295, in Decorate
>       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)   File
>   "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 1847, in FindAndLoadModule
>       description)   File "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 1295, in Decorate
>       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)   File
>   "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 1798, in LoadModuleRestricted
>       description)   File "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/datastore_admin/copy_handler.py",
>   line 40, in 
>       from google.appengine.ext.datastore_admin
>   import utils   File
>   "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 1295, in Decorate
>       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)   File
>   "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 1945, in load_module
>       return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule,
>   fullname, search_path)   File
>   "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 1295, in Decorate
>       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)   File
>   "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 1847, in FindAndLoadModule
>       description)   File "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 1295, in Decorate
>       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)   File
>   "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 1798, in LoadModuleRestricted
>       description)   File "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/datastore_admin/utils.py",
>   line 35, in 
>       from google.appengine.ext.mapreduce import
>   control   File
>   "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 1295, in Decorate
>       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)   File
>   "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 1945, in load_module
>       return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule,
>   fullname, search_path)   File
>   "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 1295, in Decorate
>       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)   File
>   "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 1847, in FindAndLoadModule
>       description)   File "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 1295, in Decorate
>       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)   File
>   "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 1798, in LoadModuleRestricted
>       description)   File "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/control.py",
>   line 26, in 
>       from google.appengine.ext.mapreduce import
>   handlers   File
>   "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 1295, in Decorate
>       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)   File
>   "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 1945, in load_module
>       return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule,
>   fullname, search_path)   File
>   "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 1295, in Decorate
>       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)   File
>   "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 1847, in FindAndLoadModule
>       description)   File "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 1295, in Decorate
>       return func(self, *args, **kwargs)   File
>   "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py",
>   line 1798, in LoadModuleRestricted
>       description)   File "/home/lwlun/AppEngine/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/handlers.py",
>   line 26, in 
>       import simplejson ImportError: No module named simplejson

Comment: Could you have multiple versions of Python installed?

Comment: As far as I know, Slackware comes with Python already. I never installed another version myself. How can I check if I have more than one version?

Comment: @David `ls /usr/bin | grep python` will tell you every installed version.

Comment: In Ubuntu, different versions turn up as pythonX.Y in /usr/bin (I don't know about Slackware), but if you're just using the default installed version, it's probably not that. The other thing to try is working out what your sys.path gets set to by the development server.

Comment: @new123456 OK I did that and there were 4 results: an executable called 'python2.6', a script called 'python2.6-config', a symbolic link to python2.6 called 'python', and a symbolic link to python2.6-config called 'python-config'. I guess this means there's only one version.

Comment: @Thomas I printed sys.path out, and there's a few paths there, and these three seemed the most relevant: '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0'. Python console says simplejson is in '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.pyc'. Do I have to add the path to the 'simplejson' folder?

Comment: @David: No, `__init__` marks it as a Python module. I think Wooble's answer below tells you what you need to know.

Comment: @David What's the actual stacktrace you get, and what URL do you get it on?

Comment: @Nick Here's the stack trace http://pastebin.com/4iEicN5k . I got it by accessing the datastore admin screen on localhost:8080/_ah/datastore_admin as user test@example.com with administrator privileges.

Comment: @David Can you edit your question and put the stacktrace there? Pastebins tend to go away after a while. Are you doing any Python path manipulation in your app? Also note that datastore_admin isn't really intended for use on the dev-appserver - it's for doing things such as transferring data between live apps.

Comment: @Nick Haven't done any path manipulations in my app. In fact, my app is the helloworld tutorial in the documentation, I did everything except upload it. I was hoping to use the datastore admin kinda like phpmyadmin is used. By the way, when I use the workaround I mentioned in my answer, the datastore admin seems to work, but it says 'Entity statistics unavailable'.

Comment: @David The phpmyadmin-syle admin is at `/_ah/admin/datastore`. You don't need the datastore_admin tool for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in a similar question: [ImportError when using Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450883/importerror-when-using-google-app-engine)

Copying the module to the app directory worked, but it kinda feels like a cheap workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Use `from django.utils import simplejson`.

dev_appserver mimics the production environment.  Nothing you install at the system level will be available for import to your scripts, to avoid imports working fine in your testing and then failing spectacularly when you deploy.  However, you don't need to bundle this particular module because it's already available in the django package installed on production (and with the SDK).

In general, you do need to include external libraries in your application directory, although you can symlink them from their installed locations and they'll generally work fine (and will be deployed to production when you deploy).

Comment: If it is available on the sdk as well, why was it giving a import error? The error was from the dev_appserver.

Comment: you need the `django.utils` part; simply using `import simplejson` won't work.

Comment: I took a look in dev_appserver.py code, and there's no 'import simplejson' there. But there's a line with 'os.path.join(DIR_PATH,'lib','simplejson')', which was part of a list declaration with several other modules. Should I comment this line and add 'from django.utils import simplejson' to the script? I feel like the files that came with the sdk shouldn't be tampered with, though.

Comment: Actually, my assertion above seems to be incorrect; the SDK *does* now have simplejson in /lib as a standalone module, as of v.1.4.1, so the above advice has been obsolete for a few weeks now.

Comment: Yes, there's a 'simplejson' directory in 'google_appengine/lib'. Not sure why it is giving off errors.

Answer (score 0):

If it in app engine SDK's lib, e.g on Mac it's

`/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/`

Copy it over to app's dir would work. It's better than pip install and then copy over, which may contain c-extension. The modules in SDK's lib path (at least simplejson) seems to have been modified to work with app engine's needs.